# How to create a list of objects in Java

Tags: java, list

What is the equivalent way to create a list of objects in Java like the C# way of doing it below (example from the web)? I have to write something in Java, but its new to me. I can't seem to find what I'm looking for when searching the web either.

```cs
List<Author> AuthorList = new List<Author>();
```

/*The following code snippet creates the Author objects and adds them to the List. */

```
AuthorList.Add(new Author("Mahesh Chand", 35, "A Prorammer's Guide to     ADO.NET", true, new DateTime(2003,7,10)));

AuthorList.Add(new Author("Neel Beniwal", 18, "Graphics Development with  C#", false, new DateTime(2010, 2, 22)));

AuthorList.Add(new Author("Praveen Kumar", 28, "Mastering WCF", true, new DateTime(2012, 01, 01)));

AuthorList.Add(new Author("Mahesh Chand", 35, "Graphics Programming with GDI+", true, new DateTime(2008, 01, 20)));

AuthorList.Add(new Author("Raj Kumar", 30, "Building Creative Systems", false, new DateTime(2011, 6, 3)));
```

Comment: You're close, but remember in java, method names start with lowercase instead of uppercase (and your variables should be too!). Try `.add(..` instead of `.Add(`

Comment: In java  `List` is an interface so you can't instatiate it. Try  `List<Author> AuthorList = new ArrayList<Author>();
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, you would just use a generic ArrayList.

```
import java.util.*;    
...    
ArrayList<Author> AuthorList = new ArrayList<Author>();
AuthorList.add(new Author("Mahesh Chand", 35, "A Prorammer's Guide to     ADO.NET", true, java.time.LocalDateTime.of(2003,7,10)));
...
```

Note that you could type the variable as 'List':

```
List<Author> AuthorList = new ArrayList<Author>();
```

But the original doesn't type to an interface, so the exact Java equivalent perhaps shouldn't either.

Comment: That was probably a great idea including the `import` statement, I can see how that would have probably been missed too.

Comment: @Bobby: I'm not sure what you mean by 'getting an option'.

Comment: When I try your suggestion I'm getting an error that my constructor cannot be applied to given types. "required: no arguments". There must be an issue with my class in how its setup? I have private variables with public getters and setters.

Comment: I was obviously getting myself confused with the basics in Java! It was my constructor that I needed to fix. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: Just as in what options are accepted or showing up in the intellisense after I type the ".add( " to my instantiated object.

Answer (score 2):

List is an interface. use ArrayList as follows:

```
List<Author> AuthorList = new ArrayList<Author>();
```

Answer (score 1):

List is an interface in java, so you cannot `new` a `List`. You can use an `ArrayList`, like this:
`List<Author> AuthorList = new ArrayList<Author>();`

Answer (score 0):

In Java, [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is an interface. Hence, you cannot instantiate it. You have to find the implementation that fits your need. Generally, [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is a good starting point. [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is quite useful too.

So you can create your list like this :

```
List<Author> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

(Note that the variable name begins with a lowercase letter : it is a Java convention).

Then, you can add some elements. In Java, every methods names shall start with a lowercase letter too. On a list, you can use the method `add()`.

```
list.add(new Author(...));
```

Note : when you want to create a list of predefined values, you can use this shortcut method :

```
List<Author> authors = Arrays.asList(
    new Author(...),
    new Author(...)
);
```

But the resulting list is immutable. Trying to add an element will raise an exception at runtime.